# ListFragment with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer, android-listfragment

Bit of a noob at android, but made it this far.
Trying to get a ListView with navigation drawer...
The following doesn't work unless I uncomment the setContentView line.  Throws a null ptr exception.  When I uncomment it, the ListView works, but the nav drawer quits showing up.
Also, the onListItemClick doesn't trigger, but that's a later problem for me to learn.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class All_Listview extends ListFragment {


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.d("onClick", String.valueOf(position));
    Activity a = getActivity();
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(a, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<WeekItem> wkList = new ArrayList<>();
    Activity a = getActivity();
//      a.setContentView(R.layout.all_listview);
    WeekAdapter adapter = new WeekAdapter(a.getBaseContext(), wkList);
    ListView lv = (ListView)a.findViewById(R.id.all_list_view);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    SQLiteHelper db = new SQLiteHelper(getActivity());
    List<Week> weeks = db.getAll();
    ArrayList<WeekItem> wkItem = WeekItem.fromList(weeks);
    adapter.addAll(wkItem);
}
}
```

I'm sure there's more to this problem than I can see at the moment, but any help is welcomed.

MainActivity

```
package com.hourtracker;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements     NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
 * navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
 * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("hours","creating session filter");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Log.d("onNavDrawerSelected", String.valueOf(position));
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position) {
    case 0:
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container,
                    ((Fragment)new Entry_Fragment())).commit();
    break;
    case 1:
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container,
                    ((Fragment)new Week_Fragment())).commit();
    break;
    case 2:
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container,
                    ((Fragment)new All_Listview())).commit();
    break;
    }
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
        break;
    case 2:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
        break;
    case 3:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
        break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container,
                ((Fragment)new Settings_Fragment())).commit();

        return true;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Not settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.hourtracker.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

all_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/all_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you post your Activity code and where is that null pointer exception?

Comment: NullPointer shows up on the line lv.setAdapter(adapter) with setContentView commented out (debugging in eclipse shows lv is null). With it uncommented, it works perfectly, but navigation drawer does nothing.  MainActivity shows something is clicked, but doesn't open the drawer.

Comment: It says null because it cant find the id: all_list_view, because you have to setContentView

Comment: Can you post your activity_main XML ?

Comment: I can post whatever can help... it's gotten uglier as I've tried whatever I could think of, so, uh, I apologize in advance for whatever ugly, ridiculous code you see here.

Comment: ps. I've tried overriding various things, this just happened to be the first one that worked for me.  Might still be wrong, but it got me closest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main error is when you create All_Listview that extends ListFragment, i suggest that you [follow this example](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/07/simple-listfragment-example-in-android.html) that helps you create Simple ListFragment

After you do it right i think the list fragment will work and even the navigation drawer too, thats because when you setContentView from ListFragment you do it wrong

Comment: So before I try it, you're saying I should deal with it in MainActivity?

Comment: No your All_Listview should be as that in example, you dont have to create that in your Activity class

Comment: It had to be called in onCreateVie() instead of onActivityCreated().